# Rename SSL app and eliminate HTTP access

Tags: ssl, heroku

Anyone know if you can:

1. rename a `herokussl.com` app? If so how? same as with regular apps: `heroku apps:rename new name`?
2. to complete SSL rollout on Heroku we need to update DNS. This means changing `www.example.com`, which currently points to our `example-production.herokuapps.com` URL, to point to `example-production.herokussl.com` (assuming I can change the cryptic app name, see 'A' above). But, in doing so that will remove any plain old `http` access to our site and force `https`...correct? Is this by design? Common practice? What happens when users simply enter `http://example.com` in their browser, exactly? Assume a redirect but is it a `301 permanent` redirect? Or...?

Apologies for apparent ignorance, I only re-activate my SSL synapses once every few years...

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you set 
    config.force_ssl = true
in your production.rb config file, so that it forces the https url

Comment: Is this a complete answer to the posted question or better served as a comment?